# How to protect access to the Wildfly HAL Management Console by Keycloak SSO using elytron-oid-client?

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

How to migrate from using keycloak-wildfly-elytron-oidc-adapter as described at https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-55623 or https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Protecting%20Wildfly%20Adminstration%20Console%20With%20Keycloak.html to protect access to the Wildfly HAL Management Console by Keycloak SSO to new elytron-oid-client in Wildfly 26.1.2 ?

According https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-15260, the ability to secure the admin console with OpenID Connect seems not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This feature currently isn't available due to [WFLY-15260](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-15260) (see comments below). Once it is implemented, the original answer quoted below should work.

> The schema of the internals is [mostly similar to that of the adapter](https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/wildscribe/subsystem/elytron-oidc-client/index.html) (except where `secure-server` is now just `secure-deployment`), so you should be able to basically copy your existing configuration from the adapter to the `elytron-oidc-client`. You can use the XML config file or an `oidc.json` file [as described here](https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/Admin_Guide.html#configuration-8).
>
> I'm not sure on the configuration when within the Admin Console itself, but it should be similar to the existing steps.

Comment: Found open issue https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-15260, so it seems the ability to secure the admin console using elytron-oid-client is not yet implemented.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the answer.